# web2py create dropdown layout.html menu

Tags: menu, web2py

I would like to create a drop down menu in my layout. The data for menu is read from menu.py

this is my list for menu

```
 response.menu_logged = [
(T('Schedules'),URL('default','index')==URL(),URL('default','index')),
(T('New schedule'),URL('script','edit')==URL(),URL('script','edit', args='new')),
(T('Workers'),URL('settings','workers')==URL(),URL('settings','workers')),
(T('Shifts'),URL('settings','turnusi')==URL(),URL('settings','turnusi')),
(T('Config'),URL('settings','config')==URL(),URL('settings','config')),
]
```

Now I would like to put workers, shifts and config in one submenu (dropdown) called settings

and in my layout.html

```
 {{if auth.is_logged_in():}}
                        <li{{ if response.menu_logged[0][1]: response.write(XML(' class="active"')) }}><a href="{{ =response.menu_logged[0][2] }}">{{ =response.menu_logged[0][0] }}</a></li>
                        <li{{ if response.menu_logged[1][1]: response.write(XML(' class="active"')) }}><a href="{{ =response.menu_logged[1][2] }}">{{ =response.menu_logged[1][0] }}</a></li>


                        <li{{ if response.menu_logged[2][1]: response.write(XML(' class="active"')) }}><a href="{{ =response.menu_logged[2][2] }}">{{ =response.menu_logged[2][0] }}</a></li>
                      <li><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/navodilawoshi/" target="_blank">{{=T('Help')}}</a></li>
```

any suggestions?

Id there is a possibility to do it with web2py and not html/css/js?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about using the "nested menu" feature as written in the applications/welcome/models/menu.py ?

You would get something like:

```
response.menu_logged = [
(T('Schedules'),URL('default','index')==URL(),URL('default','index')),
(T('New schedule'),URL('script','edit')==URL(),URL('script','edit', args='new')),
(T('Settings'), False, None, [
    (T('Workers'),URL('settings','workers')==URL(),URL('settings','workers')),
    (T('Shifts'),URL('settings','turnusi')==URL(),URL('settings','turnusi')),
    (T('Config'),URL('settings','config')==URL(),URL('settings','config'))])
]
```

You may also setup 2 menus depending on user login status:

```
if auth.is_logged_in():
    response.menu = [... full menu ...]
else:
    response.menu = [... short one ...]
```

Comment: In my view, when I click on settings i am redirected to none/index page (which does not exist).Also sub menus do not appear on mouse over or mouse click

Comment: @Yebach: that sounds odd! This example works fine in a blank test app, as main menu. I think your CSS could be involved in such a behaviour. I suggest to double check it against [MENU() helper doc](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views?search=menu#MENU).